# how do i pass the stopwatch value over to another activity

Tags: android

im trying to make a stopwatch for this quiz im making, but i dont know how to pass the stopwatch from question to question(1 question per activity). code for the stopwatch is as follows.

```
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);  
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btStart);  
    pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btPause);  
    reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btReset);  

    handler = new Handler() ;  

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View view) {  

            StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();  
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);  

            reset.setEnabled(false);  

        }  
    });  

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View view) {  

            TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;  

            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);  

            reset.setEnabled(true);  

        }  
    });  

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View view) {  

            MillisecondTime = 0L ;  
            StartTime = 0L ;  
            TimeBuff = 0L ;  
            UpdateTime = 0L ;  
            Seconds = 0 ;  
            Minutes = 0 ;  
            MilliSeconds = 0 ;  

            timer.setText("00:00:00");  

        }  
    });  

}  

public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {  

    public void run() {  

        MillisecondTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - StartTime;  

        UpdateTime = TimeBuff + MillisecondTime;  

        Seconds = (int) (UpdateTime / 1000);  

        Minutes = Seconds / 60;  

        Seconds = Seconds % 60;  

        MilliSeconds = (int) (UpdateTime % 1000);  

        timer.setText("" + Minutes + ":"  
                + String.format("%02d", Seconds) + ":"  
                + String.format("%03d", MilliSeconds));  

        handler.postDelayed(this, 0);  
    }  

};
```

have been trying for a while now but the app keeps crashing when i press the start button which leads to the first question

i have this at the start of every activity, to start the stopwatch again when a new question comes, i think this is where it crashed?

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        time = String.valueOf(millis);
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }
};
```

and run the stopwatch again in onCreate()

line that log shows the crash:

```
long startTime = Long.parseLong(getIntent().getStringExtra("time"));
```

log:

```
Process: com.example.ng_we.capsize, PID: 12385
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ng_we.capsize/com.example.ng_we.capsize.question3}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2839)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ng_we.capsize.question3.<init>(question3.java:19)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2829)
```

Comment: If app crashes, there should be an exception in Logcat. Please add that part of logcat to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- Save the stopwatch time in a global/static place.
- Pass and object over in to each class.

Comment: or... a slower way i can just start a timer for every question then on the finish page add them all up to display?

Comment: If you're doing all of this procedurally as you're new to programming, you can do!, but in future it wont be good practise.